# How to restore an account from a lost mac from time machine?

Tags: time-machine

I have 2 computers : an iMac and a MBP. My old MBP is dead. I've Time Machine backups from the accounts of this computer.

How can I restore those accounts on my iMac to have access to their data?

Comment: i've done this with command line, but it was clunky so i'm interested in what people come up with for solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5872)! Should work just fine from a TM backup.

[image]

Comment: Have you understood that I want to keep my current accounts on my iMac ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it tell you that you couldn't keep your current accounts?